# Transfer data from arrayfire arrays to armadillo structures

Tags: c++, armadillo, arrayfire

I would like to replace some of my calculations formerly written with `armadillo` with `ArrayFire`, in order to use some GPU capabilities. I do not want to replace everything, just the time-critical spots. Thus I need to convert `armadillo`-structures into `arrayfire`-structures and back. The first step is easy:

```
arma::colvec A_arma(5, arma::fill::ones);
af::array A_array(5, A_arma.memptr());//Done
```

Going back is more difficult. How do I get the data from the `arrayfire`-structure into the `armadillo`-structure? I can iterate over all elements and write them into the `armadillo` structure, but that would take a lot of time. Are there easier ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the data out of an `af::array` using the [host](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__method__mat.htm#ga67d1d90fb9f4423a68333104230d930d) member function. For example, you can copy the data from an ArrayFire array to a `std::vector` like this:

```
af::array gpu_data = af::randu(10, 10);
vector<float> cpu_data(gpu_data.elements());

gpu_data.host<float>(cpu_data.data());
```

This will copy the data in column major order to the `cpu_data` vector.

I am not too familiar with armadillo's data structure but I am sure you can pass the pointer returned by the `memptr` to the host function and the data will be copied into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert directly to an Armadillo structure with the ArrayFire array's `host` pointer.

```
size_t nrows = 10;
size_t ncols = 10;

af::array af = af::constant(0, nrows, ncols); // defaults to dtype=f32
float* host_ptr = af.host<double>();
arma::fmat arma(host_ptr, nrows, ncols);
```

Notice that the types and sizes need to match. In the above case, single precision floating point type was used. For double precision, you would have to change to the following.

```
af::array af = af::constant(0, nrows, ncols, f64); // specify dtype=f64
double* host_ptr = af.host<double>();
arma::mat arma(host_ptr, nrows, ncols);
```

For complex vectors its a bit more complicated. Armadillo uses `std::complex` while ArrayFire uses a different data structure under the hood. These should be compatible (verify for your system) so using a `reinterpret_cast` should do the trick.

```
af::cfloat* host_ptr = img_af.host<af::cfloat>(); // Assuming dtype=c32
arma::cx_fmat arma(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<float>*>(host_ptr), nrows, ncols);
```

Last but not least, be sure to free the host pointer or you will have a memory leak!

```
af::freeHost(host_ptr);
```